# Is there a better way to write " $('#sender-name')[0].value; " instead of using 0 element?

Tags: jquery

is there a better way to write

$('#sender-name')[0].value;

instead of using the 0 element... Its an id so only 1 element should be present, is there some kind of FirstElement property or first child or something?

Basically i am returning it to a variable .. but of course jquery returns an array of items but it is an id so i not interested in the array just the first item..

Any ideas?

THanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`val`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val) function: returns the value of the first element for inputs.

```
var value = $('#sender-name').val();
```

Answer (score 3):

there's always `$('#sender-name').get(0).value;` but it's conceptually the same thing.

Do you mention `value` as simply an example of a DOM property, or is this specifically what you want? maybe `$('#sender-name').val()` would help if you don't absolutely need the DOM object.